# Producing RNG vectors in R that have pre-defined sum of pdf or sum of cdf

Tags: r, random

I am a new R user and I am trying to produce vectors with numbers randomly generated based on a specific distribution (with the rnorm command for example) with the vectors having a pre-defined sum of probability densities or sum of cumulative distributions.

For example, when generating vectors x1, x2 … xn I want them to obey either

`sum(pnorm(x1)) = sum(pnorm(x2)) = … sum(pnorm(xn))`

or

`sum(pnorm(xi)) = ”fixed value”`

or do the same but with dnorm. In other words, is there a possibility to set such parameters when using rnorm or any other RNG in R?

Tips and suggestions for strategies instead of complete solutions would also be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Interesting question. My first idea would be to use somekind of antithetic variate approach. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithetic_variates

Comment: This seems more of a stats/math question than a programming question. you might want to bring it over to stat.stackexchange.com or math.sta... and then if you need help implementing asking back here

Comment: Have you noted that there is a limit how many vectors of that type there is? For example if your x1, x2,.. are all just scalars, there is only at maximum two values with identical probability in case of normal distribution (x+mu and x-mu)?

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses. To answer specifically, I believe it is a programming rather than a maths/stats question. Also, I am aware of the existence of 2 values with the same probability in case of normal distirbution, however that doesn't really change much regarding my question since it was about the sum(pnorm(x)). I believe the updated answer by Vincent Zoonekynd covers my question, but I want to thank you because your comments made me think about how to produce additional code to show what I meant and it put me on track to a correct answer. All the very best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.**
In the case of a Gaussian distribution, 
sampling from `(X1,...,Xn)` under the condition that `X1+...+Xn=s`
is just sampling from a 
[conditional Gaussian distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions).

The vector (X1,X2,...,Xn,X1+...+Xn) has a Gaussian distribution, with zero mean,
and variance matrix

```
1 0 0 ... 0 1
0 1 0 ... 0 1
0 0 1 ... 0 1
...
0 0 0 ... 1 1
1 1 1 ... 1 n.
```

We can therefore sample from it as follows.

```
s <- 1  # Desired sum
n <- 10
mu1 <- rep(0,n)
mu2 <- 0
V11 <- diag(n)
V12 <- as.matrix(rep(1,n))
V21 <- t(V12)
V22 <- as.matrix(n)
mu <- mu1 + V12 %*% solve(V22, s - mu2)
V  <- V11 - V12 %*% solve(V22,V21)
library(mvtnorm)
# Random vectors (in each row)
x <- rmvnorm( 100, mu, V )
# Check the sum and the distribution
apply(x, 1, sum)
hist(x[,1])
qqnorm(x[,1])
```

For an arbitrary distribution, this approach would require you to compute the conditional distribution, which may not be easy.

**2.**
There is another easy special case: a uniform distribution.

To uniformly sample n (positive) numbers that sum up to 1, 
you can take n-1 numbers,
uniformly in [0,1],
and sort them: they define n intervals, 
whose lengths turn sum up to 1, and happen to be uniformly distributed.

Since those points form a Poisson process,
you can also generate them with an exponential distribution.

```
x <- rexp(n)
x <- x / sum(x)  # Sums to 1, and each coordinate is uniform in [0,1]
```

This idea is explained (with a lot of pictures) in the following article:
[Portfolio Optimization for VaR, CVaR, Omega and Utility with General Return Distributions](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1856476), 
(W.T. Shaw, 2011), pages 6 to 8.

**3.**
(EDIT) I had initially misread the question, which was asking about `sum(pnorm(x))`, not `sum(x)`. This turns out to be easier.

If `X` has a Gaussian distribution, then `pnorm(X)` has a uniform distribution:
the problem is then to sample from a uniform distribution, with a prescribed sum.

```
n <- 10
s <- 1  # Desired sum
p <- rexp(n)
p <- p / sum(p) * s  # Uniform, sums to s
x <- qnorm(p)        # Gaussian, the p-values sum to s
```

Comment: `apply(x, 1, sum)`  should return the same value for all rows?

Comment: Yes: it is the desired sum, it should be (approximately) 1 for each row.

Comment: it is ok ! I have a mistake do to some sessions variable..! +1! I tried the rude way with a while ( I generate x2 until I assert the condition, x3...) but it is extremely inefficient..

Comment: I had misread the question, which was about `sum(pnorm(x))`, rather than `sum(x)`: I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. The updated answer is exactly what I wanted. I also believe I know enough to be able to jump from cdf to pdf and vice-versa in order to always get what I want. As a last request, I would appreciate it if you could direct me to any source regarding your "p <- p/sum(p) * s" transformation, I would be interested to read more about it in case it is some sort of mathematics rule (I am a biochemist by training). All the very best

Comment: I have added a short explanation as to why `p <- rexp(n); p <- p/sum(p)`
should produce constrained uniform numbers, with a reference.